# android reset/reload fragment data

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use a `ViewPager` to create 3 `Fragments` on `Activity_1`, this is the `ViewPagerAdapter`:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment1 tab1 = new Fragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Fragment2 tab2 = new Fragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Fragment3 tab3 = new Fragment3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

This is `Activity_1` which holds all `Fragments`, and automatically shows `Fragment_1` when `Activity_1` is opened :

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

    TabLayout tab_layout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Frag1"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Frag2"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Frag3"));

    final ViewPager view_pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tab_layout.getTabCount());

    view_pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab_layout));

    tab_layout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            view_pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });

}
```

Every `Fragment` can go to `Activity_2`.
`Fragment_3` holds data that can be edited on `Activity_2`.

My Problem:

When edit data from `Activity_2` and back to `Activity_1` using the back button, 
data in `Fragment_3` is still old, not changed with the edited data from `Activity_2`.
But when close `Activity_1` and open it again, data in `Fragment_3` is changed.

I think I need reset or reload `Fragment_3` when I come back to `Activity_1` from `Activity_2`, but I don't know how.

update,
this is Activity_2:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv_id;
String id;

TextView tv_d;
Button bt_add, bt_remove;

String str_find;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    id = i.getStringExtra("id");

    tv_id = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_DetailId);

    tv_id.setText(id);

    tv_d = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_Detail);
    bt_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_detail_add);
    bt_remove = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_detail_remove);

    str_find = "example";

    try {
        final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TestFolder/Test.txt");

        StringBuilder text  = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
        xml_root = text.toString();

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        int len = 0;
        byte[] data1 = new byte[1024];
        while ( -1 != (len = in.read(data1)) ){
            if(new String(data1, 0, len).contains(str_find)){
                bt_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv_d.setText("yes");
                bt_remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //something to edit data on Test.txt
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                bt_remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv_d.setText("no");
                bt_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //something to edit data on Test.txt
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use interfaces to communicate between activity or fragments and activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/38143179/6334037

Comment: @Mohammed Atif : how to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragments not updating in viewpager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685726/fragments-not-updating-in-viewpager)

Comment: Can you update your Activity2 class too

Comment: @Mohammed Atif : I was update in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `onResume()` method you can have a condition check

`view_pager.setCurrentItem(last_frag);`

where `last_frag` is a global integer whose value you set everytime in on page change listener.

this will refresh your fragment.

In your Activity1.java

make the following changes

`private ViewPager view_pager;` will be your global variable

and remove `final ViewPager` during initialization.

Make it like this in `onCreate()` Method

```
view_pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

`private int last_frag = 0;` will be your global variable in `Activity1.java`

```
@Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            view_pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            last_frag = tab.getPosition();
        }
```

Comment: i was try, but in view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener, I can't add view_pager.setCurrentItem(last_frag); code show red on setCurrentItem. may be I don't understand your explant. can you show me something you edit with my code?

Comment: so, if I understand right, in view_pager.setCurrentItem(last_frag); last_frag is int from 0 to 2 define in each fragment sent to Activity_2 and get again in Activity_1?